# How to go to particular record in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview with multiple pages of records in a.aspx.
When I click a button in b.aspx I need to go to a specific page that contains the record in the gridview.

Comment: Why do you need to go to that page? I assume that you actually want to go to a specific record instead. Then i would pass it's ID via url-parameter (or session) and then go to the page in the grid with this record. That's is better because the page might change(f.e. with sorting).

Comment: I have massive data of 1000 pages in gridview. I have a situation where i need to edit the grid view record in a another page. When I press back button it is start page I am finding very difficult to go back to particular record.

Comment: So actually it is as i've thought. Are you using VB.NET or C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you actually want to go to a specific record instead. Then i would pass it's ID via url-parameter (or session) and then go to the page in the grid with this record. That's is better because the page might change(f.e. with sorting).

Assuming that your grid lists products and you want to ensure that a perticular product is shown because you've just edited the product-details on another page. Also assuming that your `DataSource` is a `DataTable`(but it doesn't really matter):

```
/// <summary>
/// Binds the products-GridView.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ProductID">the ProductID to be displayed, changes also the PageIndex if necessary</param>
private void BindProductGrid(int ProductID = -1)
{
    DataTable tblProducts = getAllProducts();
    GridProducts.DataSource = tblProducts;
    bool needsPaging = (tblProducts.Rows.Count / GridProducts.PageSize) > 1;

    if (ProductID == -1)
    {
        this.GridProducts.PageIndex = 0;
        this.GridProducts.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int selectedIndex = tblProducts.AsEnumerable()
            .Select((Row, Index) => new { Row, Index })
            .Single(x => x.Row.Field<int>("ProductID") == ProductID).Index;
        int pageIndexofSelectedRow = (int)(Math.Floor(1.0 * selectedIndex / GridProducts.PageSize));
        GridProducts.PageIndex = pageIndexofSelectedRow;
        GridProducts.SelectedIndex = (int)(GridProducts.PageIndex == pageIndexofSelectedRow ? selectedIndex % GridProducts.PageSize : -1);
    }
    GridProducts.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Yeah your answer was very helpful to me thank you..Thats the answer I was looking for