# load specific gridview row on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Edit: I solved the problem by including an filterexpression on my gridview and a textbox for the search. That way I could pass the search query directly without doing all kinds of fancy stuff.

---

I have made a basic searchfunction. In that searchfunction, I have included a hyperlink to see more information:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSelect" runat='server' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/CompanyActive.aspx?id={0}", Eval("CompanyID")) %>'>Select</asp:HyperLink>
```

It passes on the CompanyID to my mainpage (CompanyActive) where I have a gridview with paging.

However my problem is that it doesnt go to the specific page/place where the record is located. It just shows the first page.

I think I need to put some kind of code into my pageload event on CompanyActive, but I dont know which commands I should be using.

Comment: post your navigation page code.

Comment: Navigation page code? You mean my pager-settings for the gridview?

Comment: You mean you want to show the page that specific id is exist?

Comment: Correct Jumpei. If I have 1000 records and record #500 is located on page #10, I want it to go to page 10 when I click the link.

Answer (score 2):

are you using a datatable to fill your gridview ?

if so and you know the ID is not going to change you could do the navigation on record ID

here is a link to a similar question on Stackoverflow

[How to go to particular record in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305316/how-to-go-to-particular-record-in-gridview)

Hope this helps

Martyn

Example

You are using this as your link button

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSelect" runat='server' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/CompanyActive.aspx?id={0}", Eval("CompanyID")) %>'>Select</asp:HyperLink>
```

to use the code from the other article just modify the code like this

```
 private void BindProductGrid()
    {
product ID = Request.QueryString["id"]; // id is the name same as what you passed as a querystring 
        DataTable tblProducts = getAllProducts();
        GridProducts.DataSource = tblProducts;
        bool needsPaging = (tblProducts.Rows.Count / GridProducts.PageSize) > 1;

        if (ProductID == -1)
        {
            this.GridProducts.PageIndex = 0;
            this.GridProducts.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            int selectedIndex = tblProducts.AsEnumerable()
                .Select((Row, Index) => new { Row, Index })
                .Single(x => x.Row.Field<int>("ProductID") == ProductID).Index;
            int pageIndexofSelectedRow = (int)(Math.Floor(1.0 * selectedIndex / GridProducts.PageSize));
            GridProducts.PageIndex = pageIndexofSelectedRow;
            GridProducts.SelectedIndex = (int)(GridProducts.PageIndex == pageIndexofSelectedRow ? selectedIndex % GridProducts.PageSize : -1);
        }
        GridProducts.DataBind();
    }
```

That way the ID is the companies id that you passed from the other page

Comment: No datatable. 
Everything in my gridview is populated through a sqldatasource. 

The ID is never going to change, as it is the primary key in my database.

Comment: OK, in that case that article should still work as you know the exact ID

Comment: But how can I bind the code to two seperate pages? I have two sites, search and companyactive. The hyperlink is located on search.
The article is regarding if the gridview and button is located on the same page. Or am I completly mistaken?

Comment: Yes an no, Basically the article talks about the same page, but you are able to pass it as a querystring to a new page and on the pageload of the new page set call it and use it.

I have updated my answer